# PostgreSQL PITR

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a master\server setup with pgpool and postgres 9.5. Both servers are running on centOS7.

I wanted to setup a point in time recovery with base backups every saturday, eliminating the old xlogs.

The server is archiving the xlogs with success on a external filesystem.

But when I try to execute the basebackup command it gives the following error:

> pg_basebackup: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "replication" does not exist.

Comment: Try https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: pg_basebackup requires a user with replication privs.. do you have this ?

Comment: Yes i have.on the hba

Comment: database "replication" does not exist. you are trying to backup or restore data in a non-existent database

Comment: please update post with exact command

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing the explicit HBA record for replication database, because specifying `all` does not covers the replication connections

```
host    replication    postgres             127.0.0.1/0               trust
```

> The value replication specifies that the record matches if a
>   replication connection is requested (note that replication connections
>   do not specify any particular database). Otherwise, this is the name
>   of a specific PostgreSQL database.